# Handing a completion with CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have an app that has species and photos.  I am adding cloudKit to the app.  I have a working solution, but now I need to add a completion handler as if the user downloads new species that include images, this takes some time (of course depending on how many images).  However, the app allows the user to work during most of this process as it runs in the background.

The issue is if an image is not yet fully downloaded and the user select that species the app crashes, naturally.

I need to input a completion handler (or if someone has a better idea) that will allow me to use an activity indicator until the full process is completed.  I found a few examples, but they don't take into account multiple download processes, like my images and thumbnails.

Here is my code.  Note that I have removed some of the irrelevant code to reduce the amount shown.

```
func moveSpeciesFromCloud() {

    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: RemoteRecords.speciesRecord, predicate: predicate)

    CKDbase.share.privateDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) {
        records, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            guard let records = records else { return }
            for record in records {

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    self.remoteVersion = record[RemoteSpecies.remoteSpeciesVersion] as! Int
                    self.remoteSpeciesID = record[RemoteSpecies.remoteSpeciesID] as! Int
                    self.speciesDetail = AppDelegate.getUserDatabase().getSpeciesDetails(self.remoteSpeciesID)
                    self.localVersion = self.speciesDetail.version

                    // being sure that remote version is newer than local version
                    if self.localVersion >= self.remoteVersion {

                        print("Species version not newer")

                    } else {

                        self.commonNameLabel = record[RemoteSpecies.remoteCommonName] as! String
                        self.speciesLabel = record[RemoteSpecies.remoteSpeciesName] as! String
                        self.genusLabel = record[RemoteSpecies.remoteGenusName] as! String
                        self.groupLabel = record[RemoteSpecies.remoteGroupName] as! String
                        self.subGroupLabel = record[RemoteSpecies.remoteSubGroupName] as! String
                        self.speciesDetailsLabel = record[RemoteSpecies.remoteSpeciesDetails] as! String


                        // Here I sync records to SQLite, but removed code as not relevant.


                        // now syncing Photos, Thumbs, Groups, SubGroups and Favorties

                        self.syncPhotosFromCloud(self.remoteSpeciesID)
                        self.syncThumbsFromCloud(self.remoteSpeciesID)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the Thumbnails (Images are same process)

```
func syncThumbsFromCloud(_ id: Int) {

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "thumbSpeciesID = \(id)")
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: RemoteRecords.thumbsRecord, predicate: predicate)

    CKDbase.share.privateDB!.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil)
    {
        records, error in

        if error != nil {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            guard let records = records else { return }
            for record in records {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    self.thumbName = (record.object(forKey: RemoteThumbs.remoteThumbName) as? String)!
                    self.thumbID = (record.object(forKey: RemoteThumbs.remoteThumbID) as? Int)!

                    if let asset = record[RemoteThumbs.remoteThumbFile] as? CKAsset,
                        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: (asset.fileURL)),
                        let image = UIImage(data: data)
                    {
                        let filemgr = FileManager.default
                        let dirPaths = filemgr.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                    in: .userDomainMask)

                        let fileURL = dirPaths[0].appendingPathComponent(self.thumbName)

                        if let renderedJPEGData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
                            try! renderedJPEGData.write(to: fileURL)
                        }
                    }

                    // syncing records to SQLite
                    AppDelegate.getUserDatabase().syncThumbsFromCloudToSQLite(id: self.thumbID, name: self.thumbName, speciesID: id)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I call it here on SyncVC:

```
@IBAction func syncCloudToDevice(_ sender: Any) {
    let cloudKit = CloudKit()
    cloudKit.moveSpeciesFromCloud()
    cloudKit.moveFavoritessFromCloud()
}
```

If I missed a detail, please let me know.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm kind of concerned that both the previous answers don't help answer your question.. One is asking you to restructure your database and the other is asking you to become dependent on a third-party library.

My suggestion would be to make your `perform(_:inZoneWith:)` into a *synchronous* operation so that you can easily perform one after another. For example:

```
func performSynchronously(query: CKQuery) throws -> [CKRecord] {

    var errorResult: Error?
    var recordsResult: [CKRecord]?
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    CKDbase.share.privateDB!.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { records, error in
        recordsResult = records
        errorResult = error
        semaphore.signal()
    }

    // Block this thread until `semaphore.signal()` occurs
    semaphore.wait()

    if let error = errorResult {
        throw error
    } else {
        return recordsResult ?? []
    }
}
```

**Ensure that you call this from a background thread so as to not block your UI thread!** For example:

```
// ... start your activity indicator

DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {

    do {
        let records1 = try performSynchronously(query: CKQuery...)
        // parse records1
        let records2 = try performSynchronously(query: CKQuery...)
        // parse records2

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // stop your activity indicator
        }

    } catch let e {
        // The error e occurred, handle it and stop the activity indicator
    }
}
```

Of course, please just use this code as inspiration on how to use a semaphore to convert your asynchronous operations into synchronous ones. [Here's a good article](https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/a-quick-look-at-semaphores-6b7b85233ddb) that discusses semaphores in depth.

Comment: I really like what you posted and will study it more in the morning as I just returned from a biz trip.  Question: I am running SQLite and SQLite gives me errors and many headaches if i don't run from the main thread.  Will that be an issue with your idea?

Comment: Actually, misspoke myself.  SQLite must run from a single thread and I assigned to the main thread for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Hmm I have used SQLite but if you can move it to a background thread I'd definitely recommend it - treat it like an external API: make a "request" to it and get back a "response" thread-agnostically

Comment: Max, I read the articles and like the direction a lot.  I realize the above is mostly a basic example to point me in a direction.  However, as I am still new at this coding thing, I am struggling how to utilize this in an my array.

Comment: Hey David - here's an example I threw together just now: https://gist.github.com/Jugale/eecf672e77d8e490ba1d8cf86f2e4e0d

Comment: Thank you, Max.  While I did not use you example (for more advanced than my experience), but the code did point me in the right direction and found a way to do it by simply adding the idx feature to my code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in general that sort of things are easy to do with `RxSwift`. You set activity indicator to `on`/`off` in `.onSubscribe()` and `.onTerminated()`, respectively, and you get the end result in subscriber/observer when it is ready. Specifically for `CloudKit`, you can use `RxCloudKit` library.

Comment: Question, I have no experience with RXSwift and am not using RXSwift for my app now, can I add RXSwift just for this function?

Comment: Sure you can if you are familiar with Carthage. But not using RxSwift is a big disadvantage, it makes plenty of general and iOS-specific complexity (KVO, GCD, delegates, etc.) go away.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you made the pictures a separate record type? I would just add the thumbnail and the full photo to the `Species` record type:

`thumbnail` = **Bytes** data type (1MB max)

`photo` = **Asset** data type (virtually limitless)

That way when you do your initial Species query, you will instantly have your `thumbnail` available, and then you can access the `CKAsset` like you are currently doing and it will download in the background. No second query needed which will make your code simpler.

Comment: Thanks Clifton.  The challenge I had was that different apps (TVos, MacOS) will access the same data, via custom container.  Not all apps will want the species data.  That is why I only store species ID and photo details.  Also, I may want to expand this to a larger idea and felt that separating them could prove beneficial later on.  While you are probably right, I just wanted to take the safer route.